# How can I monitoring errors in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to get errors from my React Native app, just now the app it's in production so I need a free way to get the users errors to fix it and know what happened. I am using React Native with Expo.

Comment: did you check firebase crashlytics?

Comment: I have seen how to use Firebase Crashlytics but it's necessary eject expo and I can't do that

Answer (score 0):

**Abstract / Answer**
Generally speaking, Expo offers great error detection for debugging purposes when running it in local development mode. But since you weren't specific, I'm going to assume you meant production not development. Your best bet would be using [Sentry](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/). If you would have asked me before then I would have suggested building your own module based on native events and report back using Firebase or something similar. But since Sentry is now well integrated into Expo, then your best bet is using it. It's a great platform with many features, it's definitely worth it.

Comment: Yes Sentry is the best option but if there are any way to do the same thing but free or myself I would like to know how do that

Comment: Well, there are a few. I would say you should look into creating a native branch, where you can write your own native scripts where you can register for crash events or unexpected exceptions, and then post to a backend server you run on a local pc or something such. You can also look around and check if Expo supports crash trigger events which i think they do. By doing that, all you need to do is host a server on a machine and get http requests with information on usage and crash reports. Very easy if i may say myself.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to let me know if this helped so i can update the answer, and then you may check mark it as a correct answer for future stackoverflow users sake.

Comment: I would like to wait for another answer or if I find the solution reply my own question